# icefaces4 weblogic12.1.2 jsf2.2 com.icesoft.icepush.MainServlet$ExtensionRegistration is not a listener

Tags: weblogic, jsf-2.2, icefaces

I have WebLogic12.1.3.  I upgraded to use ICEfaces-EE-4.1.0.GA and JSF2.2.13
I was trying to get things working as specified by 
https://roundwheeltech.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/deploying-a-jsf-2-2-to-weblogic-12-1-3 
None of these worked until I ended up putting javax.faces-2.2.13.jar in an external jsf.war file.  
Aside from a missing class com/icesoft/faces/webapp/CompatResourceServlet, which I got from icefaces-ee-compat-3.3.0.GA_P01, I got thing rolling. 
However, now I am getting an error,

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <1299454a-f91e-4387-b8e1-71b409f59aee-00000006> <1516514209269>

weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [HTTP:101164]User defined class 
com.icesoft.icepush.MainServlet$ExtensionRegistration is not a listener, as it does not implement the correct interface(s).

        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)

        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)

        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)

        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)

        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)

        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)

        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)

        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)

         at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)

        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)

        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)

        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)

        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)

        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)

        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)

        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)

        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)

        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)

        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [HTTP:101164]User defined class com.icesoft.icepush.MainServlet$ExtensionRegistration is not a listener, as it does not implement the correct interface(s).
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.addEventListener(EventsManager.java:602)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListener(EventsManager.java:516)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:135)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:93)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1836)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)

         at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)

        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)

        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)

        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)

        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Comment: I tried to circumvent this by adding <br/><br/>
  <listener> <br/>
    <listener-class><br/>
      com.icesoft.icepush.MainServlet$ExtensionRegistration<br/>
    </listener-class><br/>
  </listener><br/>
to web.xml

Comment: well, I saw this being old, so I updated<br/>
<faces-config 
 version="2.2"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
 >
<br/>
but now, I get an new error

Comment: <Jan 22, 2018 12:27:46 PM CST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "FOOWeb".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleState